# How to accept values from user and store it into 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D array to accept values from users. However, when I ran the code and tried to input values, it's not accepting the values.

```
int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    int[][] Array = new int[rows][cols];
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
           
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            Array[rows][cols] = entry.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            System.out.println(Array[rows][cols]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Array[i][j]` - not `Array[rows][cols]` Either way, `rows = cols = 0` so your array has room for `0` elements.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by replaying the Array[rows][cols] with Array [I][j]. Thank you, I appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of rows and columns is 0 and you are creating an array with rows and columns size. So your array will be of size 0 and won't accept any values. Try to change the values of rows and columns.

```
int rows = 5; 
int cols = 5;

int[][] Array = new int[rows][cols];  // new int[5][5];  
Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
       
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        Array[i][j] = entry.nextInt();
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        System.out.println(Array[i][j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: int rows = 5;  //for example 
    int cols = 5;
    int[][] Array = new int[rows][cols];   //int[] Array = new int[5][5]; now you have an array //                                               of size 5
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
           
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            Array[rows][cols] = entry.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            System.out.println(Array[rows][cols]);
        }
    }

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63728942/edit) your question and add the code there.